# Which single file, embeddable DBMS exist for Java?

Tags: java, database, nosql

I'd like to use an *embedded* database management system within my Java app that should store all data in *one single portable file*.

I know already that [H2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)) and [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) databases seem to fit my needs, but I'd like to see if there are other solutions that are embeddable and are able to save the whole database in a single-file.

I don't insist on relational databases, [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) solutions are welcome. For example, if [ElasticSearch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticsearch) or [Solr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Solr) could be tweaked to save data in a single file, that would be fine, too.

The solution could include both open source software or commercial software. If it's OSS, it should allow commercial use. The license costs of proprietary software should not be higher than USD 10.000 and the license should permit to distribute the database engine along with my app for an unlimited number of installations.

The database engine should be able to run on:

1. Windows, Mac OS and Linux systems as well as
2. Android and iOS ("nice to have").

Comment: If I were you, I woudl be going with Sqlite

Comment: Are absolutely dead-set on a single file, rather than a folder with a bunch of files? Since in the latter case I have a recommendation for you...

Comment: Well, yes. But maybe give your recommendation as a comment - I'm sure that someone will find it helpful.

Comment: You may be interested to try [Chronicle Map](http://chronicle.software/products/chronicle-map/). However, it is key-value database, but allow to store data in a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [firebirdsql](http://www.firebirdsql.org/) database.

> Firebird is a relational database offering many ANSI SQL standard features that runs on Linux, Windows, and a variety of Unix platforms. Firebird offers excellent concurrency, high performance, and powerful language support for stored procedures and triggers. It has been used in production systems, under a variety of names, since 1981.

It has friendly license.

This [article](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq350/) explains how to use it in embedded mode. (In short - you must place firebird.dll/firebird.so to system PATH before starting your java app)

Comment: Thank you. I used Interbase/Firebird back in my Delphi time. But is it single file now? If I remember correctly, the databases consisted of a bunch of files.

Comment: I think it store database in single `.fdb` file.